# Python 2.7.5 error printing list of float numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7, precision, floating-accuracy

I was trying to answer a question from here ([Substracion of two items from two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33671799/subtraction-of-two-items-from-two-lists-in-for-command)). The original problem has two different lists with float values and the goal is to zip them and substract

This code works fine:

```
Enter=[7.12, 7.14, 7.24, 7.45, 7.28, 7.31, 7.18, 7.25, 7.33, 7.38]
Leave=[7.56, 7.24, 7.48, 7.52, 7.45, 7.57, 7.22, 7.31, 7.37, 7.41]
intervals = map(lambda x, y: y-x, Enter, Leave)
```

Then:

```
print intervals
```

Output:

```
[0.4399999999999995, 0.10000000000000053, 0.24000000000000021, 0.069999999999999396, 0.16999999999999993, 0.26000000000000068, 0.040000000000000036, 0.059999999999999609, 0.040000000000000036, 0.030000000000000249]
```

Which seemed really weird for me. And tried this:

```
print intervals[0]
```

Output:

```
0.44
```

And, last:

```
for i in intervals:
    print i
```

Output:

```
0.44
0.1
0.24
0.07
0.17
0.26
0.04
0.06
0.04
0.03
```

---

So the question is. Why is printing floating values one by one print the correct value, while printing entire list doesnt?

Just as a note, I'm using Live Sympy for testing it ([Live Sympy](http://live.sympy.org/), don't have python installed here) which runs Python 2.7.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The print method formats the float however when you print the list it doesn't format its internal values and prints as it is.

```
    >>> print(intervals[0])   <== formatting is done by print here
    0.44
    >>> intervals[0]
    0.4399999999999995

    >>> print (type(intervals))
    <type 'list'>
    >>> print (type(intervals[0]))
    <type 'float'>
```

Comment: Just tried intervals[0] and gives the same output as printing it :S
`>>> intervals[0]`
`0.44`
`>>> print intervals[0]`
`0.44`

Comment: Seems like changes due to Live Sympy

Comment: Yes, it seems like a problem with Live Sympy as it gave me this `>>> intervals`
`[0.44, 0.1, 0.24, 0.07, 0.17, 0.26, 0.04, 0.06, 0.04, 0.03]`
`>>> print intervals`
`[0.4399999999999995, 0.10000000000000053, 0.24000000000000021, 0.069999999999999396, 0.16999999999999993, 0.26000000000000068, 0.040000000000000036, 0.059999999999999609, 0.040000000000000036, 0.030000000000000249]`